# A sampling problem

Tags: pr.probability, asymptotics

I have a suspicion that the question I am about to ask  is classical.  I could not trace a reference,   and I am really curious about the answer. Here is the question,

An urn contains $m$ balls labelled $1,\dotsc, m$.  Sample with replacement the urn. Denote by $N=N_m$ the  first moment you sample a ball you have sampled before. One can find easily the distribution of $N_m$ and its mean. $\newcommand{\bE}{\mathbb{E}}$ More precisely, the mean is
$$
\bE[N_m]=2+\sum_{k=2}^m\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\Big( 1-\frac{j}{m}\Big).
$$
Numerical experiments suggest that $\bE[N_m]=o(m)$ as $m\to \infty$. Is anyone aware of precise asymptotics of $\bE[N_m]$ as $m\to \infty$?

Thank you.

Comment: It's the "birthday problem" and indeed it's very widely studied indeed. For the expected time to the first match specifically, looks like there's a nice answer at  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941394/birthday-problem-asymptotics-of-expected-time-until-a-match-occurs/1944572 , giving $E(N_m)=\frac12\sqrt{2\pi}\sqrt{m}+\frac23+O\left(\frac1{\sqrt{m}}\right)$ but google may well provide other leads too.

Comment: Another phrase for searching for related stuff is "capture-recapture".

Comment: @JamesMartin  Thank you very much! I should have seen it's the birthday problem.